# How to change the C# StringBuilder.AppendLine line ending?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, line-endings

I have an old application in C# and use `StringBuilder.AppendLine` to add lines with strings and then calculate a Checksum over the string.
Until now this was always running on Windows Desktop/Windows CE, so the line ending was always `\r\n`.

Now I need to make it work identically on linux/mono. But then `AppendLine` adds only a `\n` instead of a `\r\n`.

So I have to add the identical line endings to the stringbuilder as on windows. But how?

```
s.Append("\r\n");
```

doesn't seem to work.

```
s.Append(13);
s.Append(10);
```

doesn't do the job, either.

Comment: why not add your own extension method?

Comment: _"doesn't seem to work"_ - why not? _"doesn't the job too"_ - why not? What _is_ the result if you do that?

Answer (score 6):

`StringWriter` could be used to write to a `StringBuilder`.

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
using var stringWriter = new StringWriter(builder)
{
    NewLine = "\r\n"
};

stringWriter.WriteLine("line1");
stringWriter.WriteLine("line2");

var output = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the value the `StringBuilder` uses. The [source](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs) uses `Environment.NewLine`, which will be `\n` on a Linux system. There's no overload. You will have to implement your own method, or just append like `s.Append("13\r\n");`

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(false)]
        public StringBuilder AppendLine(string value) {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<StringBuilder>() != null);
            Append(value);
            return Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
const string LineEnd = "\r\n";
s.Append(LineEnd);
```

adds a line end in windows style also on unix/linux.

Comment: From your question: _"`s.Append("\r\n")` doesn't seem to work."_. Then why would this work?